# How to install / setup Eslint, Prettier into a react app?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

I am learning React, and now I am trying to understand the eslint, prettier, and install into my react project.

BUT I am confused about how to set this up, and what order to do this.

I am using create-react-app to create the app and then using JavaScript.

Comment: You can install them locally with `npm install --save-dev prettier` and write scripts for it to auto format your code, and do things like check for errors on pull requests. Or you can then install the eslint/prettier plugin for your editor, like vscode, and use the editor integration to format code on save, and show errors from eslint inline.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would start with reading the [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/), install eslint using a package manager, and create your `.eslintrc.json` config file.

Once you have added eslint, then you need to add prettier to your config. Follow how to add prettier [from their github](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier). You need to install it with a package manager, then extend your eslint with prettier.

Your `.eslint.json` should look like

```
... 
"extends": [
   "some-other-config-you-use",
   "prettier"
]
```